# Oauth token is being revoked after sometime

Tags: linkedin-api

We are using [linkedin-ads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/?view=li-lms-2022-07) API in our integration in which the OAuth token is being used to authenticate API requests. But while doing testing, we observed that the refresh token do not work after some time. In the status, it shows like `token is revoked. But, none of us have revoked any tokens. It seems like Linkedin had revoked Oauth tokens because in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/programmatic-refresh-tokens?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-07) it is mentioned that Linkedin reserves the right to revoke it. So, we just wanted to know that is there any specific reason or activity which can lead to revoking the OAuth token.

Any help would be appreciated.